# Perfect forwarding - what's it all about?

Tags: c++11, terminology, perfect-forwarding

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Advantages of using forward](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3582001/advantages-of-using-forward)

Could someone please explain to me what perfect forwarding is about?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

http://www.justsoftwaresolutions.co.uk/cplusplus/rvalue_references_and_perfect_forwarding.html

> Why is this useful? Well, it means that a function template can pass its arguments through to another function whilst retaining the lvalue/rvalue nature of the function arguments by using std::forward. This is called "perfect forwarding", avoids excessive copying, and avoids the template author having to write multiple overloads for lvalue and rvalue references.

Answer (score 14):

Quoting [Session Announcement: Adventures in Perfect Forwarding](http://cppandbeyond.com/2011/04/25/session-announcement-adventures-in-perfect-forwarding/):

> Perfecting forwarding is an important C++0x technique built atop
>   rvalue references.  It allows move semantics to be automatically
>   applied, even when the source and the destination of a move are
>   separated by intervening function calls.  Common examples include
>   constructors and setter functions that forward arguments they receive
>   to the data members of the class they are initializing or setting, as
>   well as standard library functions like make_shared, which
>   “perfect-forwards” its arguments to the class constructor of whatever
>   object the to-be-created shared_ptr is to point to.

Comment: The link you provided in this answer no longer exists...

Comment: Just came around here. Maybe this saves someone a bit of time. https://cppandbeyond.wordpress.com/2011/04/25/session-announcement-adventures-in-perfect-forwarding/