# How to move an unique_ptr from a parameter pack inside a template method

Tags: c++, templates, unique-ptr

I want to pass a parameter pack into a template method that creates a new instance of an object of a type specified by another template argument.

**Minimal code example**:

my code actually does more operations with the created type and the handler

```
template<typename T, typename... Args>
static bool CreateAndDo(Handler & rHandler, Args.. args)
{
  auto pT = T::Create(args...);
  rHandler.DoStuff(std::move(pT));
}
```

Simple Usage:

```
Handler tHander;
// the 0 is just an example of an argument
CreateAndDo<ConcreteType>(tHander, 0);
```

Now my problem is that one of my arguments is a `std::unique_ptr`.

```
auto pPtr = std::make_unique<ConcreteArg>();
CreateAndDo<ConcreteType>(tHander, std::move(pPtr));
```

This fails to compile, because the `std::unique_ptr` would have to be moved by `CreateAndDo` Method. 
I know that I need to keep moving the arguments but I don't know how to do that with a parameter pack.

How could I accomplish this?

Comment: ```std::forward``` exists exactly for such things. Please take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6829241/perfect-forwarding-whats-it-all-about

Comment: Thank you! If you add an answer I will accept it :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, why *don't* you move `args...`?

You're always copying, inside CreateAndDo. There's no reason to, and it forbids you from passing move-only args, as you've found.

I can't see that this has anything to do with templates or parameter packs, really, unless the issue is that it was unclear how to accomplish a move in that situation. The question isn't how to pass a `unique_ptr` to a parameter pack, but what to do with it afterwards, and that is just the same as you would without a parameter pack — move a `unique_ptr` around.

You should [*forward*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/forward) the args, which effectively does a move when appropriate and a copy otherwise. You'll need the argument to be a [forwarding reference](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39552272/560648), too.

```
template<typename T, typename... Args>
static bool CreateAndDo(Handler & rHandler, Args&&.. args)
{
  auto pT = T::Create(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
  rHandler.DoStuff(std::move(pT));
}
```

So the problem is that you only *moved* at one part of the chain of function calls, but not the second part, resulting in an unnecessary — and sometimes impossible — copy.

Comment: Perfekt answer! Thank you very much! You are right with your assumption that I didn't know how to move it inside a template. Should I rephrase the question?

Comment: Might not hurt tbh. At least the title and perhaps add into the question that you know you need to keep moving the args but don't know how to do that with a pack

Comment: @TheShmoo: Nice one

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Shouldn't that be `std::forward<Args>(args)...`, i.e. without the `&&`?

Comment: @j6t: Yes, it absolutely should :)

Comment: Ah, and the parameter should then actually be `Args&&... args`.

Comment: gaaaaaaaaaaaaah

Comment: @TheShmoo Please be sure to check out the updates - thanks to j6t!