# R-value references and std::make_unique

Tags: c++

Say I have an initialised object `Foo_obj` of a class `Foo` and wish to create a unique smart pointer to a copy of this object. The code `auto pointer = make_unique<Foo>(Foo_obj)` executes and does exactly this. However when looking at the [reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/make_unique) for `std::make_unique`, this only accepts R-value references as arguments and calls the constructor of the respective class with these arguments.

My understanding is that an object such as `Foo_obj` is an l-value and thus the above code should not compile. What am I missing?

Comment: They are "universal references".

Comment: this might help [Perfect Forwarding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6829241/perfect-forwarding-whats-it-all-about)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have something like `template <typename T> void foo (T&& rt) {...}` something called reference collapsing happens and that's what Meyers calls "A universal reference". In a nutshell, if you pass an rvalue, this becomes an rvalue reference, if you pass an lvalue, this becomes an lvalue reference. This way, the function perfectly forwards all the parameters to the constructor of the `unique_ptr`.

Learn more about the universal references in [this](https://isocpp.org/blog/2012/11/universal-references-in-c11-scott-meyers) blog post by the man himself.