# C++11 variadic templates calling a function inside a class

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates, std-function, callable

I'm learning variadic templates in C++11. How can I call `test.finder` as a functional argument of `test.var_finder`?

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

class c_test {
    public:

        double finder(double a, double b = 0) {
            return a + b;
        };


        template<typename... Args>
        double var_finder(double c, Args... args, std::function<double (Args... args)> func) {
            return c * func(args...);
        };
};

int main () {
    c_test test;

    std::cout << test.var_finder(0.1, 2, test.finder) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

My expected result is 0.1 * (2 + 0) = 0.2.

Comment: What is your desired output of `var_finder(1,2,3, test.finder)`? Is it `1*(2+3+4)`?

Comment: Why are `finder` and `var_finder` in a class?

Comment: @김선달 I just included the expected result.

Comment: @Nelfeal They are just a dummy example to learn precisely how to call functions inside a class with variadic templates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you're a bit mixing the variadic template part with a bit of design-flaw

Let's start.

**Preamble**: the correct way to deal with variadic templates is to use `rvalue-reference` and `std::forward` to achieve **[perfect forwarding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6829241/perfect-forwarding-whats-it-all-about)**.

**1)** **The easy way**: you don't need class at all

you're actually not referring to any member so a class bring only complexity. It's better to refer to a free function for these cases

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

double finder(double a, double b = 0) {
    return a + b;
};

template<typename Func, typename... Args>
double var_finder(double c, Func&& f, Args&&... args) {
    return c * std::forward<Func>(f)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
};

int main () {
    std::cout << var_finder(0.1, finder, 2, 0) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

[Demo 1](http://cpp.sh/73wrq)

your function accept 2 parameters so you have to pass zero as second argument.

**2) Using a class**

The problem with your attempt is you want to call  `c_test.var_finder` with a function of `c_test` itself. Now you have to figure what kind of design you want. You can make 2 assumption. First is "I want anyway a finder function inside my class", then you have to make it `static` because it really does not use class member so you don't need an instance of `c_test`, right? so using a free function or a static member function leaves the `var_finder` implementation and you just have to call it this way

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

class c_test {
    public:
        static double finder(double a, double b = 0) {
            return a + b;
        };


        template<typename Func, typename... Args>
        double var_finder(double c, Func&& f, Args&&... args) {
            return c * std::forward<Func>(f)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
        };
};

int main () {
    c_test test;

    std::cout << test.var_finder(0.1, &c_test::finder, 2, 0) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

[Demo 2](http://cpp.sh/4ugpb)

second assumption you can do is "nope, I want any function member to be called with var_finder regardless where it comes from". I strongly discourage this approach because is carving a solution from a bad design, so I suggest to rethink your design to fall to solution 1 or 2.

**3) Bonus**: a nice design

You can add a non-variadic function and delegate the usage to the use of a lambda, which allow you to use a member function inside it without defining a variadic template to deal with that (and it is the common implementation for the std library functions).

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

double finder(double a, double b = 0) {
    return a + b;
};

template<typename Func, typename... Args>
double var_finder(double c, Func&& f, Args&&... args) {
    return c * std::forward<Func>(f)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
};

template<typename Func, typename... Args>
double var_finder(double c, Func&& f) {
    return c * std::forward<Func>(f)();
};

class c_test
{
public:
    double finder(double a, double b = 0) {
        return a + b;
    };
};

int main () {
    double a = 2.0;
    double b = 0.0;

    // use as usual
    std::cout << var_finder(0.1, finder, a, b) << std::endl;

    // use with lambda
    std::cout << var_finder(0.1, [a,b](){ return a+b; }) << std::endl;

    // lambda with member argument, less gruesome than a variadic template calling a member function
    c_test c;
    std::cout << var_finder(0.1, [a,b, &c](){ return c.finder(a,b); }) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

[Bonus Demo](http://cpp.sh/9olg)

Answer (score 1):

Your solution has a lot of problems:

1) You can not convert a member function to a `std::function`, because the member function can never be called without an object. You can solve this problem by making the member function `static` or use `std::bind` or use a lambda.

2) You can not have a variadic argument list in the mid of method parameters. Variadic arguments must go to the end of the parameter list.

3) You can not deduce template arguments "on the fly" inside the parameter list itself. Solution: Use a new template parameter with a default template argument.

4) I see no chance to have default arguments for a function which we want to use in a std::function with reulting different signature `double(double)` vs `double(double,double)`

```
class c_test {
    public:

        static double finders(double a, double b = 0) {
            return a + b;
        };

        double finder(double a, double b = 0) {
            return a + b;
        };


        template<typename... Args, typename F= std::function<double(Args...)> >
            double var_finder(double c, F func, Args... args) {
                return c * func(args...);
            }
};

int main () {
    c_test test;

    // use static member
    std::cout << test.var_finder(0.1, test.finders,  2.,3.) << std::endl;

    // use lambda instead of all the hacky things
    std::cout << test.var_finder(0.1, [&test](double p1,double p2){ return test.finder(p1,p2); },  2.,3.) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do this:

```
class c_test 
{
public:

   double finder(double a, double b = 0) 
   {
      return a + b;
   };


   template<typename Func, typename... Args>
   double var_finder(double c, Func func, Args... args) 
   {
      return c * func(args...);
   };
};

int main() 
{
   c_test test;
   auto f_1 = std::bind(std::mem_fn(&c_test::finder), test, std::placeholders::_1, 0);
   auto f_2 = std::bind(std::mem_fn(&c_test::finder), test, std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2);

   std::cout << test.var_finder(0.1, f_1, 2.0) << std::endl;
   std::cout << test.var_finder(0.1, f_2, 2.0, 3.0) << std::endl;

   return 0;
}
```

and the result is:

```
0.2
0.5
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple things to deal with here.

First, put the parameter pack `args` at the end, otherwise the compiler doesn't know where to stop matching arguments with it (unless you specify the template arguments).

```
template<typename... Args>
double var_finder(double c, std::function<double (Args... args)> func, Args... args)
```

Second, don't name the parameter in `std::function`; also just don't use `std::function`, use a function pointer instead.

```
template<typename... Args>
double var_finder(double c, double (*func)(Args...), Args... args)
```

Third, make `finder` static, otherwise you run into member function pointers and the syntax is more difficult to grasp (more on that later).

```
static double finder(double a, double b = 0)
```

Third, provide the optional argument for `finder`. Otherwise, the parameter pack can't be deduced because it doesn't match both `func` and `args`.

```
std::cout << test.var_finder(0.1, c_test::finder, 2.0, 0.0) << std::endl;
```

This gives you the following.

```
class c_test {
public:
    static double finder(double a, double b = 0) {
        return a + b;
    }

    template<typename... Args>
    double var_finder(double c, double (*func)(Args...), Args... args) {
        return c * func(args...);
    }
};

int main () {
    c_test test;

    std::cout << test.var_finder(0.1, c_test::finder, 2.0, 0.0) << std::endl;
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4d9c52ecd355f9cc)

If you really need `finder` to not be static, then you have to deal with member function pointer syntax.

First, the parameter `func` must be a member function pointer.

```
double (c_test::*func)(Args...) // parameter declaration
&c_test::finder // argument in call
```

Then, you need to pass a `c_test` variable to `var_finder` in order to call `func`.

```
template<typename... Args>
double var_finder(double c, double (c_test::*func)(Args...), c_test test, Args... args) {
    return c * (test.*func)(args...);
}
// [...]
std::cout << test.var_finder(0.1, &c_test::finder, test, 2.0, 0.0) << std::endl;
```

That gives you the following code.

```
class c_test {
public:
    double finder(double a, double b = 0) {
        return a + b;
    }

    template<typename... Args>
    double var_finder(double c, double (c_test::*func)(Args...), c_test test, Args... args) {
        return c * (test.*func)(args...);
    }
};

int main () {
    c_test test;

    std::cout << test.var_finder(0.1, &c_test::finder, test, 2.0, 0.0) << std::endl;
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cfb64d3e91dfc545)

If you want to be able to call `finder` without specifying the optional parameter, then you need some intermediary, like a lambda.