# Passing any function with any number of arguments to another function

Tags: c++, multithreading, arguments

I am trying to create a C++ function that takes any function with any number of arguments and pass it to `std::thread` to start a thread with it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

#define __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ __FUNCSIG__

void runFunctionInThread(void(*f)()) { std::thread t(f); t.join(); }
void runFunctionInThread(void(*f)(int), int value) { std::thread t(f, value); t.join(); }
void runFunctionInThread(void(*f)(int, int), int value1, int value2) { std::thread t(f, value1, value2); t.join(); }

void isolatedFunc1()                       { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << "\n"; }
void isolatedFunc2(int value)              { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << " value is " << value << "\n"; }
void isolatedFunc3(int value1, int value2) { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << " value1+value2 is " << value1 + value2 << "\n"; }

int main() {

    runFunctionInThread(&isolatedFunc1);
    runFunctionInThread(&isolatedFunc2, 2);
    runFunctionInThread(&isolatedFunc3, 3, 3);
}
```

Is there anyway to create a single `runFunctionInThread` function that works for any function with any number of arguments and any type?

Comment: Use variadic templates for this

Comment: Also [`std::packaged_task`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/packaged_task) behaves this way.

Comment: Also, calling `join()` to wait on a thread immediately after creating the thread is a complete waste of the thread. `std::thread t(f(...)); t.join();` Would be no different than just calling `f(...)` by itself.  You likely want to use `detach()` instead of `join()`

Comment: @RemyLebeau Might be UB to use `std::cout` after `main` returns. `detach` is almost always problematic.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux to work around that, you would have to save the `thread` objects you create, and then `join()` on them at a later time.

Comment: Thank you for your comments folks. I know `std::thread` takes any function and arguments. However, `runFunctionInThread` does other stuff besides starting a thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [variadic template](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack) with [perfect forwarding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6829241/) of its parameters, eg:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

#define __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ __FUNCSIG__

template<class Function, class... Args>
void runFunctionInThread(Function f, Args&&... args) {
    std::thread t(f, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    t.detach();
}
 
void isolatedFunc1()                       { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << "\n"; }
void isolatedFunc2(int value)              { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << " value is " << value << "\n"; }
void isolatedFunc3(int value1, int value2) { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << " value1+value2 is " << value1 + value2 << "\n"; }

int main()
{
    runFunctionInThread(&isolatedFunc1);
    runFunctionInThread(&isolatedFunc2, 2);
    runFunctionInThread(&isolatedFunc3, 3, 3);
}
```

However, this is fairly redundant since `std::thread` can handle this directly for you, so you don't need `runFunctionInThread()` at all, eg:

```cpp
int main()
{
    std::thread(&isolatedFunc1).detach();
    std::thread(&isolatedFunc2, 2).detach();
    std::thread(&isolatedFunc3, 3, 3).detach();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your great answer, exactly what I wanted. I know `std::thread` does this for me. However, `runFunctionInThread` does other stuff besides starting a thread.

Comment: May I have your thoughts on this related question as well? https://stackoverflow.com/q/65347599/1227860

Comment: @AFPP You have already received plenty of good comments and answers on it

Comment: @ Remy of course, based on your great, great solution.

Comment: Hi Remy, I would truly appreciate your thoughts on this related question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/65352975/1227860