# Passing any class member function with any number of arguments to a function outside the class

Tags: c++, multithreading, class, variadic-functions

[Remy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/65863/remy-lebeau) posted a great solution to pass any function with any number of arguments to `std::thread`, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65347180/1227860). I was wondering how it could be used for class member functions.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>

#define __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ __FUNCSIG__

std::mutex my_mutex;

template<class Function, class... Args>
void runFunctionInThread(Function f, Args&&... args) {
    // Beside starting a thread, this function performs other 
    // task using the function and its arguments.
    std::thread t(f, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    t.detach();
}

class MyClass
{
public:
    MyClass() {};

    void myFunc1() { std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(my_mutex); std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << "\n"; }
    void myFunc2(int value) { std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(my_mutex); std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << "value is " << value << "\n"; }
    void myFunc3(int value1, int value2) { std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(my_mutex); std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << "value1+value2 is " << value1 + value2 << "\n"; }

    void manager() {
        void (MyClass::*f1)() = &MyClass::myFunc1;
        void (MyClass::*f2)(int) = &MyClass::myFunc2;
        void (MyClass::*f3)(int,int) = &MyClass::myFunc3;

        runFunctionInThread(f1);
        runFunctionInThread(f2, 2);
        runFunctionInThread(f3, 3, 3);
    }

};

void isolatedFunc1() { std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(my_mutex); std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << "\n"; }
void isolatedFunc2(int value) { std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(my_mutex); std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << " value is " << value << "\n"; }
void isolatedFunc3(int value1, int value2) { std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(my_mutex); std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << " value1+value2 is " << value1 + value2 << "\n"; }

int main()
{
    runFunctionInThread(&isolatedFunc1); // Works flawlessly
    runFunctionInThread(&isolatedFunc2, 2); // Works flawlessly
    runFunctionInThread(&isolatedFunc3, 3, 3); // Works flawlessly

    MyClass m;
    m.manager();

}
```

Comment: i suppose this is an exercise, but note that creating a thread and immediately calling `join` blocks any concurrency. Your code is quasi sequential

Comment: `std::thread` already handles this for you. It just needs to know which object's member to call. Pass `this` as the first argument after the function pointer.

Comment: This looks like a use case for [`std::async`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/async) rather than `std::thread`.

Comment: Which part or Remy's solution isn't working for you? The first argument to `std::thread` is either a function or a member function pointer and `std::thread` does the Right Thing with that. If you want to do something _like_ what `std::thread` does for your own use, you want to have a look at [`std::invoke()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/invoke).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to call a member function you'll need to pass the object to `std::thread` too:

```
void manager() {
    //...
    runFunctionInThread(f1, this);
    runFunctionInThread(f2, this, 2);
    runFunctionInThread(f3, this, 3, 3);
}
```

Note:
I noticed that you detach your threads. You then need to manually make sure that they have ended before your program does or you are in for surprises at program exit if they are still running.

It's often easier to keep the running threads in a container (like a `std::list<std::thread>`) and `join()` them later. In C++20 you could even make it [`std::list<std::jthread>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/jthread) to have them automatically joined when the container is destroyed.

Comment: ... and, obviously, take the address of the member function: unlike normal functions, member functions do not decay into pointer to member functions.

Comment: @DietmarKühl If I read OP:s code correctly, that's what it does, or am I missing something?

Comment: @TedLyngmo: yes, indeed. I thought it is worth pointing that out, as it isn't clear from the answer.

Comment: @DietmarKühl Oh,ok. I got worried there for awhile :-)