# A Server Class Taking Any Function To Run in Thread With Passing a Server-Generated Value

Tags: c++, multithreading, class, templates, variadic-functions

I am trying to write a server class with a method that takes a function as an argument and pass in a value (generated inside the server class) to the function for being run inside a thread.

The following is just an example to illustrate what I am trying to do. My goal is to have the `Server::runFunctionInThread` general enough that works for methods of different classes as well as for functions that do not belong to any classes. Is this a possible thing to do?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#define __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ __FUNCSIG__
std::mutex my_mutex;
// *****************************************************************************************
class Server
{
public:
    // With this class method, I am trying to get the function pointer A::FA, B::FB, and FC, 
    // then generate a value, and ultimately start a thread with the functions and 
    // the generated value.
    template<class Function, class... Args>
    void runFunctionInThread(Function f, Args&&... args) {
        // This function does other tasks in addition to starting a thread and 
        // for the sake of this example, they are removed for simplicity.

        int valueGeneratedInServer = rand() % 100;
        // Pass in the generated value to the function and start a thread with it.
        std::thread t(f, std::forward<Args>(args)..., valueGeneratedInServer);
        t.detach();
    }
};
// *****************************************************************************************
class A
{
public:
    void FA(int value) {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(my_mutex);
        std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << " value = " << value << "\n";
    }

    void run() {
        Server s;
        s.runFunctionInThread(&A::FA, this);
    }
};
// *****************************************************************************************
class B
{
public:
    void FB(int value) {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(my_mutex);
        std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << " value = " << value << "\n";
    }

    void run() {
        Server s;
        s.runFunctionInThread(&B::FB, this);
    }
};
// *****************************************************************************************
// A function that does not belong to any class
void FC(int value) {
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(my_mutex);
    std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << " value = " << value << "\n";
}
// *****************************************************************************************
int main()
{
    A a;
    a.run();

    B b;
    b.run();

    Server s;
    s.runFunctionInThread(&FC, 3);

    while (true) {};
}
```

The compiler complains with an error `'std::invoke': no matching overloaded function found`. Could someone kindly shed light on this, please?

Comment: Have you tried the code you show? What problems (if any) do you have with it?

Comment: Yes, I get `'std::invoke': no matching overloaded function found`.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the error you get, copy-pasted in full and complete (including any informational notes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before we got your problem, why you don't define the `Server`, `A` and `B` constructors ?

So, your problem is with functions argument. You just sent a function address to your `Server`:

```cpp
s.runFunctionInThread(&A::FA, this);
...
s.runFunctionInThread(&B::FB, this);
...
s.runFunctionInThread(&FC, 3);
```

And use it wrongly:

```cpp
std::thread t(f, std::forward<Args>(args)..., valueGeneratedInServer);
```

Because of non-member functions which don't have a `self` parameter. Or if you change your code to this:

```cpp
template<class Function, class Arg>
void  runFunctionInThread(Function f, Arg arg)
{
  int  valueGeneratedInServer = rand() % 100;

  std::thread  t(f, valueGeneratedInServer);
  t.detach();
}
```

It won't work with member function, so i suggest you to use `std::bind` and `std::function` like this:

```cpp
template<class Function>
void  runFunctionInThread(Function f)
{
  int  valueGeneratedInServer = rand() % 100;

  std::thread  t(f, valueGeneratedInServer);
  t.detach();
}
```

And use it:

#### For member functions:

```cpp
Server  s;
s.runFunctionInThread(std::bind(&A::FA, this, std::placeholders::_1));
```

#### For non-member functions:

```cpp
Server  s;
s.runFunctionInThread(std::bind(&FC, 3));
```

Comment: Can I achieve the same thing using lambda functions?

Comment: Yes of curse you can.